# How to swipe right (vertical) in particular box, and verify all results in Android with Appium

Tags: android, android-layout, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Scenario is swipe right to left at a box. and you will get some dynamic result. and verify them.

Comment: Please add more details. Do you know what object you are looking for when swiping, or do you know the exact distance you need to swipe. Also woudn't swipe to the right be horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

U can Identify locators for 2 elements -

1 - Element till where u want to reach

2 - A Common Xpath for All Horizontal Elements in that box and run following code to Scroll Horizontally.

```
public static void scrollTillElementHorizontally(By by, By allElements) {
    if (driver.findElements(By) > 0 || driver.findElement(By).isDisplayed())
        return;

    int y = driver.findElement(allElements).getCenter().y;
    int width = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
    double startX = width * 0.80;
    double endX = width * 0.20;
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50) {
        if (driver.findElements(By) > 0 || driver.findElement(By).isDisplayed())
            break;
        action.press(PointOption.point((int) startX, y)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
                .moveTo(PointOption.point((int) endX, y)).release().perform();
        i++;
    }
}
```

And if u want to remove duplicate elements while scrolling add the elements to HashSet which would remove duplicates while scrolling.